# Getting 'No results found' message in Discover tab of Kibana 4.0.1 but data exists in index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have data in an index called 'documents' containing a single type called 'invoice' with nested types containing mostly primitive values:

```
{
    header: { shipToCity, ... },
    lineItems: [{ qty }, ...],
    additionalInfo: { shipToCity2 }
}
```

When I specify the index pattern 'documents' in the **Settings** tab then move to the **Discover** tab, there is a message indicating that there are no results found and all of the fields are hidden.

[image]

Pretty much every document will be missing at least one field but a majority of the fields contain values.  It's hard to see in the image below but I have the time filter set to the last 10 years.

Why does Kibana fail to find/display any results?

#### Update/Solution

I think this was a result of the root document not containing a timestamp field.  In the document example above, `header`, `lineItems`, and `additionalInfo` are nested objects and I was trying to use a field on the header as the timestamp field in Kibana.

Adding a field called `timestamp` to the root document seems to have solved the problem:

```
{
    timestamp: 2015-3-13,
    header: { shipToCity, ... },
    lineItems: [{ qty }, ...],
    additionalInfo: { shipToCity2 }
}
```

Comment: By default it only takes last 15 minutes data. Can you see if that is the issue ?

Comment: Yes, I guess you can't really see it in the image but the time filter is set to the last 10 years in which there are many documents.

Comment: @calvdee I seem to have a similar problem as you had...at least regarding the fact Kibana didn't display any result. Do you have any idea what could be wrong in my case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371953/kibana-doesnt-show-any-results-in-discover-tab